# Double sound notification when plugging in iPhone X with Fast Charge

Tags: iphone, usb, charging, power, lightning

I recently purchased an iPhone X, and along with it I also purchased a 29W USB-C Power Adapter and a USB-C—Lightning cable. This setup is supposed to enable Fast Charging of the iPhone X.

However, always when plugging in the iPhone X to this setup, the phone gives a way the "charging" sound notification twice. Is this normal behaviour?

I don't get the double sound notification when plugging in via normal Lightning-to-USB-A to another 12W adapter, nor when connecting the phone with a Mac.

I'm thinking the second sound notification may have something to do with switching over to Fast Charge, but I haven't been able to find a definite answer. Or perhaps some component is faulty?

This thread *(external link)* has people asking the same thing:
https://forums.imore.com/iphone-x/396144-fast-charge-apple-ac-adapter-cable-double-sound.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double chime is definitely a bug rather than a feature. it's caused by the switch from regular charging speed to the fast charging speed. when the power adapter takes too long to make the switch (I guess we're talking about 10s or 100s of milliseconds), the iphone thinks it got disconnected and reconnected again.

That explains why some chargers cause iphones to make a double chime and some don't. Mine is a 3rd party charger and I've never had a double chime on my iphone 11, even though I'm 100% sure it's double charging (I connected it through a wattage meter and I can clearly see that the switch from 5W to 18W happens)

edit: you can refer to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f9n9IyEeuuE&ab_channel=%E7%A8%BB%E8%8D%B7%E5%A3%BD%E5%8F%B8) (not mine, but underlines what I just wrote)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **when fast charging iPhone gives the charging sound ("Ding") notification twice**. And definitely you will **not get sound notification twice when you have used the 12W iPad charger**.
**12W Charger** => The downside is that while it’s faster than the brick that comes with your phone, it’s still not quite the true quick charging speed that a USB-C brick should offer. Simply you could not get the true fast charging. But it is better than what comes with the box.

**29W Charger** => Apple isn’t saying what the maximum fast charging speed is for the new phones — only that it achieved those fast charging results with its 29W, 61W, and 87W USB-C chargers for the new MacBooks and MacBook Pros. These chargers offer the best fast charging power where you hear the charging sound twice.

References : [(EasyAcc, 2017)](https://www.easyacc.com/media-center/how-to-tell-if-my-iphone-8-x-is-fast-charging/), [(Apple Inc., 2017)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208137) , [(The Verge, 2017)](https://www.theverge.com/2017/11/3/16599178/iphone-x-8-plus-apple-fast-charging-usb-c-lighting-power-brick-cable-how-to).

Comment: PS: Does Fast Charging still make the sound twice, in iOS 12? For some reason, my iPhone X with a 29W USB-C adapter doesn't make the double sound anymore. Not sure if it's Fast Charging or not.